# Будет ли экономиться размер файла если в параметры функции передавать не значения а указатели?

Tags: c++, c

Например есть 2-е функции

```
void func1(int ValueA, int ValueB)
{
    int a = ValueA + ValueA;
    int b = ValueB + ValueB;
}

void func2(int* PtrValueA, int* PtrValueB)
{
    int a = *PtrValueA + *PtrValueA;
    int b = *PtrValueB + *PtrValueB;

}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    func1(a, b);
    func2(&a, &b);

}
```

Если я правильно понял то если в функцию передавать значения а не указатели как в `func1` то при компиляции для параметров функции `func1` будет выделена доп. память т.е. будет выделена память на переменные a, b в функции `main` + будет выделена память для параметров `func1`. Из этого у меня и возник вопрос с точки зрения размера файла не будет ли выгоднее передавать указатели?

Comment: Это называется — экономить на спичках. Тем более что точно так же будет выделена память под локальные указатели (или точно так же не выделена из-за оптимизации) + разыменования... Да и указатели могут быть больше `int`. Если вы собираетесь передавать килобайтные, грубо говоря, структуры — ну, тогда дело другое. Только вот при чем здесь *размер **файла*** — вообще не понимаю...

Comment: Harry, боюсь, он желает уменьшить размер исполняемого файла после компиляции.

Comment: На спичках? Или на терабайтах? Параметры могут быть объектами, а объекты бывают гигантскими.

Comment: Экономия на размере параметра – это экономия стека. А файл сравнивайте самостоятельно для своей реализации языка.

Comment: Для уменьшения размера файла используйте upx

Answer (score 2):

Память для переменных *может* выделятся в стеке *(сразу выделенный участок памяти при старте программы)* а не в файле. Размер файла не будет меняться, так как место памяти, где хранится программа и локальные переменные функции - разные.

*По-умолчанию* в Си переменные имеют отметку автоматического хранения :

```
auto int a = ..
```

это значит, что переменные могут храниться или в стеке или в регистрах процессора или в самих командах `mov %%rax, 10`.

При передачи указателями `void func2(int* PtrValueA, int* PtrValueB)` компилятору уменьшается возможность оптимизировать и код функции должен брать значения по выданному указателю и так-же для передачи аргументов, должна быть выделена память (*часть стека*).

Параметры функций также имеют по-умолчанию автоматическое место хранения и передаются *копии*. Никакой разницы для аргументов не будет, будь они числа или указатели.

Ответ :

Размер программы не имеет отношения к локальных переменным.
При передачи аргументов копией `func1` может быть оптимизирована память в стеке.
Если аргументы не помещаются в размеры регистров процессора, тогда создастся *копия* в стеке.

Обычно простые переменные передают копией *(с надеждой на оптимизацию)*, а структуры/объекты указателем/ссылкой.

Answer (score 2):

Тоже отвечу, но немного с другой колокольни. Если речь идёт об экономии размера скомпилированного "экзешника", то вопрос смысла не имеет. В исполняемых файлах присутствуют выравнивания, так что одним байтом больше, одним меньше - разницы не будет никакой. А вот что действительно имеет значение, так это производительность кода. И да, передача параметров типа `int` по значению будет эффективнее, чем передача указателей, т.к. в последнем случае понадобятся дополнительные операции по извлечению этих самых значений из указателей (разыменование). Так что если функция оперирует значениями передаваемых *простых* переменных (имеющих тип `int`, `float`, и т.д.), то и передавать следует значения этих переменных, а не указатели.

Однако для ясности разберём ваш пример. Дизассемблируем ваш код и посмотрим, сколько машинных инструкций и какие содержат функции `func1()` и `func2()`. Пугаться ассемблера тут не стоит, ибо нас интересует в данный момент только количество сгенерированных компилятором инструкций, а их смысл я дополнительно укажу в комментариях. И так, вот он, вид функции `func1()` после компиляции:

```
func1     proc near
          retn
func1     endp
```

Теперь функция `func2()`:

```
func2     proc near
          retn
func2     endp
```

Как видим, обе функции содержат только одну инструкцию - `retn` (нетрудно догадаться, что это оператор `return;`). Обе функции ничего не делают и занимают в коде ровно 1 байт! Как так получилось? А просто ваши функции действительно ничего не делают. Да, там присутствуют какие-то арифметические вычисления над локальными переменными, однако результат никуда не сохраняется, локальные переменные `a` и `b` после возврата уничтожаются. Компилятор увидел это, и весь ненужный код удалил.

Так что сделаем так, чтобы обе функции сохраняли результат своих вычислений, ну скажем, в некоторую дополнительную структуру, указатель на которую (именно указатель, а не значение), передадим через третий параметр. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
struct RESULT
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void func1(int ValueA, int ValueB, RESULT* pRes)
{
    pRes->a = ValueA + ValueA;
    pRes->b = ValueB + ValueB;
}

void func2(int* PtrValueA, int* PtrValueB, RESULT* pRes)
{
    pRes->a = *PtrValueA + *PtrValueA;
    pRes->b = *PtrValueB + *PtrValueB;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    RESULT res;
    func1(a, b, &res);
    func2(&a, &b, &res);
    return 0;
}
```

Теперь первая функция в скомпилированном коде будет выглядеть так (смысл каждой инструкции прокомментирован):

```
func1           proc near

ValueA          = dword ptr  4
ValueB          = dword ptr  8
pRes            = dword ptr  0Ch

                mov     eax, [esp+ValueA] ; берём ValueA
                mov     edx, [esp+pRes] ; берём указатель pRes
                add     eax, eax        ; складываем ValueA + ValueA
                mov     [edx], eax      ; записываем результат в pRes->a
                mov     eax, [esp+ValueB] ; берём ValueB
                add     eax, eax        ; складываем ValueB + ValueB
                mov     [edx+4], eax    ; записываем результат в pRes->b
                retn                    ; выходим из функции
func1           endp
```

А вторая так:

```
func2           proc near

PtrValueA       = dword ptr  4
PtrValueB       = dword ptr  8
pRes            = dword ptr  0Ch

                mov     eax, [esp+PtrValueA] ; берём указатель PtrValueA
                mov     edx, [esp+pRes] ; берём указатель pRes
                mov     eax, [eax]      ; извлекаем значение *PtrValueA
                add     eax, eax        ; складываем *PtrValueA + *PtrValueA
                mov     [edx], eax      ; записываем результат в pRes->a
                mov     eax, [esp+PtrValueB] ; берём указатель PtrValueB
                mov     eax, [eax]      ; извлекаем значение *PtrValueB
                add     eax, eax        ; складываем *PtrValueB + *PtrValueB
                mov     [edx+4], eax    ; записываем результат в pRes->b
                retn                    ; выходим из функции
func2           endp
```

И того, функция `func1()` содержит 8 команд процессора, а функция `func2()` - уже 10 комманд, т.к. две дополнительные инструкции приходятся на разыменование указателей. Так что первая функция хоть чуть-чуть, но производительнее второй. А что касается их размера в байтах, то он неважен. ОК, вторая функция на 4 байта длинней первой - это фитюлька, которую вообще не стоит учитывать! Тем более, что из-за выравнивания на размер кода в целом эта разница никак не скажется.

Ещё раз: производительность - вот, на что надо ориентироваться при написании кода, а не на размер (а если всё таки хочется уменьшить размер исполняемого файла, то для этого существуют специальные архиваторы-упаковщики, на подобие UPX и ему подобные).

И да, выше приведённый разбор справедлив, если в качестве параметров передаются простые типы данных, такие как `int`, `float`, `double` - всё, что до восьми байт длинной. Большие же массивы и структуры целесообразно передавать через указатель или ссылку, в противном случае процесс передачи таких больших значений будет занимать несравненно больше времени, чем обращения по указателю.

Надеюсь, я вам подкинул пищу для размышлений))